# Why am I failing to capture the "this" pointer by a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, this

Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        auto functor = [this]() 
            {
                A * a = this;
                auto functor = [a]() // The compiler won't accept "this" instead of "a"
                    {
                        a->bar();
                    };
            };
    }

    void bar() {}
};
```

In VC2010, using `this` instead of `a` lead to compilation errors. Among others:

```
1>main.cpp(20): error C3480: '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>::__this': a lambda capture variable must be from an enclosing function scope
1>main.cpp(22): error C3493: 'this' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified
```

Which I don't understand. Does it mean it doesn't know if it should use a reference or copy it? When trying to use `&this` to force referencing, it also says:

```
1>main.cpp(20): error C3496: 'this' is always captured by value: '&' ignored
```

The temporary is not that annoying, but for the sake of curiosity, is there a way to get rid of it? What goes on when `this` is given to a lambda?

Comment: Works fine in GCC 4.6.1, even with `[this]`.

Comment: This looks like [bug #560907](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560907/capturing-variables-in-nested-lambdas) (closed as `WONTFIX`, unfortunately).

Comment: So `auto functor = [=]()` can be the work around ? I think !!

Comment: @NeelBasu No, unfortunately, because then `this` represents the functor: `error C2039: 'bar' : is not a member of '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a compiler bug in VS2010. I was able to make it work by letting the inner lambda implicitly capture `this`:

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        auto functor = [this]() 
        {
            auto functor = [=]()
            {
                bar();
            };
        };
    }

    void bar() {}
};
```

---

> When trying to use &this to force referencing, it also says:
>
> 1>main.cpp(20): error C3496: 'this' is always captured by value: '&' ignored

`this` can only be captured by value. `[=]` and `[&]` both capture it by value.

> What goes on when this is given to a lambda?

I don't know but it must be something special because you can't use `this` in a lambda as a pointer to the lambda object. Anything else *captured* becomes a private member of the lambda so presumably `this` does too but there's some special handling on usage.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a known bug with the Visual Studio 2010 compiler](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560907/capturing-variables-in-nested-lambdas) (as referenced by Frédéric Hamidi's comment).

You have to explicitly capture `this` to pass it to another lamba's capture specification. This also applies to local variables declared outside the lambda's enclosing lambda, even with a `[&]` capture specification.